# Weird behavior of typescript when checking a promise using generic type

Tags: typescript, promise

I'm trying to get the compiler to check the type of a promise, but I get a strange behavior. Here are 4 different `return` options I tried:

```
interface MyResponse<T> {
  foo: number,
  data: T,
}

const g: () => Promise<MyResponse<number>> = async () => {

  // This behavior is fine, the compiler complains, as expected:
  // ERROR: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  return {
    foo: 1,
    data: 'wrong type'
  }

  // Both foo and data are missing, but I get no error. I don't get why
  return {}

  // data is missing, but still no error
  return {
    foo: 1
  }

  // Now the compiler complains about `data` being missing
  // ERROR: Property 'data' is missing in type '{ foo: number; bar: string;  }'.
  return {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 'this fails'
  }

}
```

It's worth noticing that if I don't use `Promise` (nor `async`), then I get the expected errors.

Any idea why this is happening ?

[EDIT]: This is related to a typescript bug that should be fixed with typescript 2.4 (see [discussion on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15702#event-1075203007))

@nitzan-tomer's answer is still a good workaround until the next release.

Comment: 1st option is not fine. You are making a MyResponse<number> that means the data property is a number but you are trying to set a string in it. That's why it complains.

Comment: What is fine is that the compiler complains, as expected :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that this problem is resolved when you change the signature of the function a bit:

```
const g = async (): Promise<MyResponse<number>> => {
    ...
}
```

With your original signature this happens:

```
const g1 = async () => {
    return {}
}

const g2: () => Promise<MyResponse<number>> = g1
```

The type of `g1` is `() => Promise<{}>` and the compiler thinks that it's ok to assign this type into `() => Promise<MyResponse<number>>`.

It only complains when the structure of the return value conflicts with the structure of `MyResponse`.

---

#### Edit

This issue is fixed as of version 2.4.
Original issue: [Weird checking errors when using async function, and generic typings](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15702).
Related to: [Generic parameter inference for Promise.then oddity](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11022).
Fixed in: [Covariant checking for callback parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/15104).

Comment: There's still a problem here though, and I see you opened an issue for it: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15702

Comment: Yeah, this still looks a bit suspect to me. In particular the last error message is strange. I really hope I'm not mistaking but it seems to me there is room for improvement here.